# How to get ScrollableResults with Gorm DetachedCriteria?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

In Hibernate i can do:

```
// dc - DetachedCriteria
ScrollableResults sr = dc.getExecutableCriteria(getSession()).scroll()
```

But how to do the same with Gorm DetachedCriteria?

```
DomainName.withSession { session ->
    DomainName.where {
       // predicates
    }.getExecutableCriteria(session).scroll()
}
```

Code above will fail, because method not exists.

**Updated:**
I have found this solution:

```
 def hiberSession = Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.sessionFactory.currentSession
 def hiberDc = HibernateCriteriaBuilder.getHibernateDetachedCriteria(null, gormDc)
 def sr = hiberDc.getExecutableCriteria(hiberSession).scroll()
```

But the outgoing SQL has no columns in query:

```
select from domain_name where ... ;
```

**Updated:** I dug deeper and have found solution for previous problem.

```
hiberDc.setProjection(null)
```

---

Why this happens?

When you pass your detached criteria (gorm) to `getHibernateDetachedCriteria` and your detached criteria has no projections, then new detached criteria (hibernate) will have empty list of projections instead of `null` - [proof](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/8b0672e3e5047593037e556da111294acbcaf8af/grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate/src/main/groovy/grails/orm/HibernateCriteriaBuilder.java#L177).

Well, what of it?

Hibernate expects `null` in `projection` for generating all columns self - [proof](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/d0c2c31ab7217da32eee2a82457eb321a3aebbaa/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/loader/AbstractEntityJoinWalker.java#L107)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, answer to my question will be:

```
def currentSession = Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.sessionFactory.currentSession
def hibernateDetachedCriteria = HibernateCriteriaBuilder.getHibernateDetachedCriteria(null, gormDetachedCriteria)
def criteria = hibernateDetachedCriteria.getExecutableCriteria(currentSession)
if (!criteria.projection) criteria.projection = null
def scrollableResults = criteria.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY)
```

Comment: Two notes. First, depending on where your code is you can probably skip the first line and just add a property  'def sessionFactory'  to have the sessionFactory injected into your object.  2nd depending on the type of your query this may not work, I am currently getting a NPE on HibernateCriteriaBuilder.java line 222   [grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]

Comment: Thanks for notes. Can you show your query which cause NPE?

Comment: Sure, it's really plain. Since comments are short, I dumped a small integration test onto github - https://github.com/rrsIPOV/gormDc101/blob/master/src/integration-test/groovy/gormDc/DetCritToDetCritIntSpec.groovy   , the  gormDetachedCriteria.list() method works fine, but the code above fails w/ the NPE (grails 3.1.1)

Comment: Possibly this solution may not work for Grails 3.x, but it should properly work for Grails 2.4.x. I think HibernateCriteriaBuilder was changed since 2.4.x.